# Why am I getting these errors in my console on this nodejs weather app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the link to the github repo for my code.

https://github.com/Messan93/Messan93-WeatherJournal.io

[Console error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyIl1.png)

Everything seem to be fine but these are the errors am still getting. I can see what the error message is but I don't see anything wrong with the code on that line.

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative URLs on those API calls you're making, and since you're opening your `index.html` directly from your file system rather than serving it through a server, the paths are relative to your file system.

The simplest fix (just to get your example working) would be to provide absolute URLs instead:

Change `postData('/add'` to `postData('http://localhost:3000/add'`
and `await fetch('/all')` to `await fetch('http://localhost:3000/all')`

A more real-world fix would be to serve the `index.html` file from your express server.